# Media server (DLNA) which works with Picasa database

Tags: photography, dlna

I have an enormous collection of family photos which resides on a network share on home network. I connect to it with Picasa whose own metadata database is also on that share. Local Picasa is mapped to its database through a hard directory link and I use same setup on all my computers, which lets me browse and otherwise work with the photos with Picasa software on any PC - works fine.

What I lack is the ability to view photos on my smart TV because it of course doesn't have a Picasa client, at any rate not one which could work with database on the net somewhere.

What I would ideally like to be able to do is to expose the albums defined in Picasa through a DLNA interface carried out by PC software on one of my computers. That the TV would understand fine and I wouldn't have to mess with additional computers connected to it.
I'd write this software myself (probably will do eventually), but I'd have to learn both DLNA and (worse) Picasa data structure. 
Google Media Server seemed to be something in that direction, but it's long since abandoned and only works on long since abandoned Google Desktop, so nope...